# Switching Center to Objects

Tags: modeling

[image]

Here's an interesting situation I'm facing right now. During modelling, I know that you make it easier to focus on an object by PRESSING PERIOD on your numpad. That way, the rotation will be oriented within that object.

My problem now is that my fullsize keyboard has gone caput and I'm now using a replacement keyboard with no NUMPAD at all.

So, during my modelling, I am having difficulty manimuplating the 3D space because I cannot control or place the CENTER to a specific object.

Is there a solution within the KEYS themselves?

Thanks

Comment: Change the hotkey to something you can use.  Keyboards send codes for specific keys, if your keyboard doesn't have that key it can't send the correct code.  Remapping is your only option, other than buying a new keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header of a 3D view, right-click on the *View > Frame Selected* menu item, and add it to your Quick Favorites and/or create a new keyboard shortcut for it.

Comment: THIS IS THE ANSWER I AM LOOKING FOR. The next thing for me is to REMAP this to a key combination or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is personal preference but I never use the period key to focus on things, turning this options ON are all you should need when modeling. This are under Blender preferences -> Navigation. Try it out, might change your life :). Some people like to have the orbit around selection option turned on but I find it slows me down.